# Descending counter in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

If i use

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
```

inside a for-each loop in xsl it works great for an ascending counter. Is there any way to change it to a descending counter?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about as simple as...

```
<xsl:value-of select="last()-position()+1" />
```

As [fn:last](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-last) returns the context size, and [fn:position](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-position) - the position of the currently processed item, you just have to substract 1 from their difference (as `position` starts its count from 1, not 0).

Answer (score 2):

**You may not need a descending counter at all** (I guess this counter is used for indexing a node-set to process it in reverse order) -- just use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="yourNodeSet">
 <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" data-type="number"/>

 <!-- Your processing here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```