# Descend variable counter using xsl:number

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am looking to use variable to have a date that needs to be counted in descendant order, e.g. (2021-01-01, 2020-01-01). I have simplified the code and it just treats the year.

The reason I am using a variable is because in the larger code I need to call data from JSON.

I have found this SO question that talks about "[descending counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348143/descending-counter-in-xsl)", but the answers are perfomed without variable.

---

**Problem:** The result comes in ascending order.

**Data source (XML/JSON):**

Not used in this example.

You find the same code in this [xsltfiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS83).

**Code:**

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to 2">
         
        <xsl:variable name="counter">
            <xsl:number start-at="2016" value="position()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
         
      </xsl:for-each>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>20162017`

**Wanted Result:**

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>20172016`

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and why you have returned to use `xsl:number` and `position()`. Note that XSLT/XPath 2 and later have a date datatype in the form of `xs:date` that also supports arithmetic operations like e.g. substracting a year: `current-date() - xs:yearMonthDuration('P1Y')`. In the end using such operations might make more sense than using `for-each`, `xsl:number` and `position()` in a rather wild combination to output date values.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I realize it makes sense to secure that the strings are treated as dates. I will go for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems somewhat contrived. Perhaps this can help you:

```
<xsl:for-each select="reverse(1 to 2)">
    <xsl:variable name="counter">
        <xsl:number start-at="2016" value="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

There is probably a simpler way to accomplish whatever this is supposed to accomplish.